# How to keep RadixUI Tooltip/Modal in dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radix

I'm using RadixUI library (https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/tooltip) for my components. The problem is that I'd like to keep the content of my Tooltip in `dom`. Currently, it appears only on hover and is rendered in `body` element as a last child. What I'd like to obtain is that:

1. Tooltip content is always kept in dom (for example with `display: none` style)
2. Tooltip content is rendered inside my tooltip trigger or at least in a way that its possible to identify with which trigger its associated

**EDIT**
Currently I have the following

```
    <TooltipProvider delayDuration={0}>
      <Tooltip open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <TooltipTrigger asChild>
          <span>{label}</span>
        </TooltipTrigger>
        <TooltipContent forceMount    className={cn(
      'z-50 rounded-sm border bg-popover px-3 py-1.5 text-sm text-popover-foreground shadow-md animate-in fade-in-0 zoom-in-95 data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-0 data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[side=bottom]:slide-in-from-top-2 data-[side=left]:slide-in-from-right-2 data-[side=right]:slide-in-from-left-2 data-[side=top]:slide-in-from-bottom-2',
      open ? "" : "hidden
    )}}>
          {content}
        </TooltipContent>
      </Tooltip>
    </TooltipProvider>
```

The remaining drawback - closing animation does not work with `hidden` class. Is it possible to make it works?

Comment: Most of Radix components has a `forceMount` prop that control the mounting state of the component. I think you can use this prop and control the visibility with CSS.

Comment: You are right. I did that (updated question) but closing animation does not work. Do you have any suggestions how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can achieve that by passing an `open` prop to the `Tooltip.Root`:

```
// instead of 'true' you can use any boolean variable
<Tooltip.Root open={true}>
  ...other stuff
</Tooltip.Root>
```

This way you will always have your tooltip in the DOM. Hence, you should be able to add any CSS you want.

2. You can simply remove the `Tooltip.Portal` and your tooltip will be rendered in the same place as where you've added it in your JSX

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my question, do you have any suggestions how to make closing animation works as well when using `hidden` class?

Comment: @Ugus the main thing is to not use `display: none;` style in your css class. just google it and you'll find tons of info on animations using css